# How to Add nameserver as echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf using docker file

Tags: python, docker

I need to add nameserver as 8.8.8.8 in /etc/resolv.conf using docker file

I used below command
echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf in docker file but not working.
When I tried same command inside docker conatainer it is working.

Please help me on this issue to resolve using docker file

Comment: Which form of command did you use inside your dockerfile? The array-based one or the single string? If using the array-based one shell redirection won't work because a shell isn't invoked.

Comment: You can't change this in the Dockerfile.  Docker always provides its own copy of the file when the container starts, and you need to provide these settings using `docker run` options.